# How to perform year subtraction in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

> I want set minimum date and year dynamically in thymeleaf. MInimun
> date = current date -21 year I want to set this type of minimum date
> value but In thymeleaf it is not possible for me  I get issue to set
> minimum date Year
> this is my max date value

```
th:attr="max=${#dates.format(#dates.createNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"
```

> my minimum date value is

```
min="${max -21}"
```

> But This line of code is not able to set minimum date
> I want to set minimum date year start from -21 year of current date
> It shows me minimum date current date year back to 1940, But I want it
> show minimum date  year from 2000 to  1940.Between 2000 to 2021 dates
> miss from the calender for minimum date site

Comment: You could write something horrible like this: `th:min="${#numbers.formatInteger(#dates.format(#dates.createNow(), 'yyyy') - 21, 0) + #dates.format(#dates.createNow(), '-MM-dd')}"` - and it would still not handle leap-days correctly. A better approach: perform the date arithmetic on the server, using `java.time` classes - for example: `LocalDate.now().minusYears(21);`.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by "_Between 2000 to 2021 dates miss from the calender for minimum date site_".